# Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 error

Tags: xcode, clang, exit-code

Just updated Xcode to 4.3 and now I can't build my app.  I'm getting this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Anybody else having this problem?  It's probably just a compilation setting but I'm not sure where to look.

Of course, the error includes the entire stack dump, but I've not included that for sake of brevity.  I'm hoping that someone will know what "exit code 254" is.  Tried searching for it but couldn't find anything.

Here's the entire output:

```
CompileC /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.o iDB/SCheckBox.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/aaron/Dropbox/XCode Projects/iDB"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -iquote /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iDB-Prefix-aojkwzmrifipbudgsdryqwbhphsf/iDB-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.dia -c "/Users/aaron/Dropbox/XCode Projects/iDB/iDB/SCheckBox.m" -o /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.o

0  clang             0x000000010a5c15a2 _ZL15PrintStackTracePv + 34
1  clang             0x000000010a5c1a29 _ZL13SignalHandleri + 553
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff94b6dcfa _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff6929a1b0 _sigtramp + 18446744072978875600
4  clang             0x0000000109ef3798 _ZL20findRetainCycleOwnerPN5clang4ExprERN12_GLOBAL__N_116RetainCycleOwnerE + 312
5  clang             0x0000000109ef35af clang::Sema::checkRetainCycles(clang::ObjCMessageExpr*) + 303
6  clang             0x00000001097efaef clang::Sema::BuildInstanceMessage(clang::Expr*, clang::QualType, clang::SourceLocation, clang::Selector, clang::ObjCMethodDecl*, clang::SourceLocation, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::SourceLocation>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::ASTMultiPtr<clang::Expr*>) + 6479
7  clang             0x00000001097ee18a clang::Sema::ActOnInstanceMessage(clang::Scope*, clang::Expr*, clang::Selector, clang::SourceLocation, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::SourceLocation>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::ASTMultiPtr<clang::Expr*>) + 138
8  clang             0x00000001097ee04b clang::Parser::ParseObjCMessageExpressionBody(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation, clang::OpaquePtr<clang::QualType>, clang::Expr*) + 2091
9  clang             0x00000001097ed7f4 clang::Parser::ParseObjCMessageExpression() + 852
10 clang             0x0000000109765597 clang::Parser::ParseCastExpression(bool, bool, bool&, bool) + 6807
11 clang             0x0000000109763ab2 clang::Parser::ParseAssignmentExpression() + 114
12 clang             0x0000000109763a21 clang::Parser::ParseExpression() + 17
13 clang             0x00000001097b8efe clang::Parser::ParseExprStatement(clang::ParsedAttributes&) + 46
14 clang             0x00000001097634bc clang::Parser::ParseStatementOrDeclaration(clang::ASTOwningVector<clang::Stmt*, 32u>&, bool) + 1564
15 clang             0x00000001097627d9 clang::Parser::ParseCompoundStatementBody(bool) + 409
16 clang             0x0000000109763242 clang::Parser::ParseStatementOrDeclaration(clang::ASTOwningVector<clang::Stmt*, 32u>&, bool) + 930
17 clang             0x00000001097b6d0b clang::Parser::ParseIfStatement(clang::ParsedAttributes&) + 475
18 clang             0x000000010976353c clang::Parser::ParseStatementOrDeclaration(clang::ASTOwningVector<clang::Stmt*, 32u>&, bool) + 1692
19 clang             0x00000001097627d9 clang::Parser::ParseCompoundStatementBody(bool) + 409
20 clang             0x0000000109edbd30 clang::Parser::ParseLexedObjCMethodDefs(clang::Parser::LexedMethod&) + 272
21 clang             0x000000010980483e clang::Parser::ParseObjCAtEndDeclaration(clang::SourceRange) + 158
22 clang             0x00000001097e2222 clang::Parser::ParseObjCAtDirectives() + 386
23 clang             0x0000000109723e87 clang::Parser::ParseExternalDeclaration(clang::Parser::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, clang::Parser::ParsingDeclSpec*) + 759
24 clang             0x0000000109723b19 clang::Parser::ParseTopLevelDecl(clang::OpaquePtr<clang::DeclGroupRef>&) + 249
25 clang             0x000000010970688b clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool) + 299
26 clang             0x00000001097053d9 clang::CodeGenAction::ExecuteAction() + 857
27 clang             0x00000001096d793f clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 879
28 clang             0x00000001096d65cb clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) + 2683
29 clang             0x00000001096c8dce cc1_main(char const**, char const**, char const*, void*) + 5086
30 clang             0x00000001096a35d8 main + 648
31 clang             0x00000001096a3344 start + 52
32 clang             0x0000000000000071 start + 18446744069256629601
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple i386-apple-macosx10.6.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name SCheckBox.m -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 128.2 -g -coverage-file /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -dependency-file /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -iquote /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iDB-Prefix-aojkwzmrifipbudgsdryqwbhphsf/iDB-Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG=1 -D IBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -D IBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -D IBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -D __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -I /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Flexile-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/1y/fbhzgfpn2ld9qxdfpgl7d_rm0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Werror -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-arc -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.dia -o /Users/aaron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDB-cvvkmobzsecywdherzjesrjswdng/Build/Intermediates/iDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flexile.build/Objects-normal/i386/SCheckBox.o -x objective-c /Users/aaron/Dropbox/XCode Projects/iDB/iDB/SCheckBox.m 
1.  /Users/aaron/Dropbox/XCode Projects/iDB/iDB/SCheckBox.m:36:47: current parser token ';'
2.  /Users/aaron/Dropbox/XCode Projects/iDB/iDB/SCheckBox.m:27:146: in compound statement ('{}')
3.  /Users/aaron/Dropbox/XCode Projects/iDB/iDB/SCheckBox.m:29:102: in compound statement ('{}')
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/1y/fbhzgfpn2ld9qxdfpgl7d_rm0000gn/T/SCheckBox-GckJrn.mi
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/1y/fbhzgfpn2ld9qxdfpgl7d_rm0000gn/T/SCheckBox-GckJrn.sh
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

**UPDATE**
So I noticed that the dump refers to specific lines on code in a specific class (SCheckBox.m).
It's in an init method.  I've checked over the method but could not find anything wrong with it.  However, if I comment everything inside the method out and return nil, the code compiles.  I went through and uncommented every line until I got the error.  The error causing the problem is this:

```
[super.inputField addSubview:_checked];
```

I had intended on using 'self' instead of 'super'(which was a typo on my part).  But super does in fact have a inputField property.  It's not redefined or overwritten in the subclass.  So accessing 'super.inputField' vs 'self.inputField' should access the exact same thing (and did before upgrading Xcode).  OK, so changing 'super' to 'self' does fix the problem.

My question now is: Why?

Comment: From the menu bar, choose View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator.  Click on the latest build log.  Find the line for the failed command.  Click the line.  Click the button at the right end of the line to reveal the command and its output.  Paste the command and output into your question.

Comment: Well, the entire output is long.  But I'll add it.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the bug although it's not in Objective C code. I get it when I try to use lambda expressions in C++. So it seems like the issue is not isolated to the dot syntax in Objective C methods.

Comment: Oh one more thing... I don't get why the first line of the error says that clang version 1.0 is being used. Anyone know why that would be?

Comment: @Mattia I recommend filing a separate bug with Apple since the bug I filed with them for this issue dealt exclusively with objective-c.  I'm not sure why it would say clang version 1.0.  I would double check your project settings and make sure your Compiler is 'Apple LLVM compiler 3.1' (or 3.0 on older Xcode).  If it is, then I believe you should be fine.

Comment: @AaronHayman Good idea to put in a different bug report - all the more likely it will get fixed. THere is no option that for selecting 1.0 (and I've checked  that my version is 3.1) so I don't think it's a problem with my settings. 

P.S. - It's mentioning that it's version 1.0 in your log as well (check the end of the first line of the log).

Answer (score 8):

I managed to trigger this issue on Xcode 4.3.2 by trying to output through NSLog the result of an in-place operation (which returns void).

In my case, what I was trying to do was:-

```
NSLog(@"result = %@", [array filterUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

The fact that `filterUsingPredicate:` is an in-place method that returns `void` seems to have triggered this compiler error. It's interesting that Xcode's as-you-type error detection doesn't pick up on it.

Changing this to the correct version:-

```
NSLog(@"result = %@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Works fine and resolves the issue!

Answer (score 3):

You've found a compiler bug.  It looks like the compiler's error report pinpoints where in your code it's barfing, so your best bet is to fiddle with that code and see if you can make it more easily digestable.

You could also submit a bug report, but that will not solve your problem in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yep, just added a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Copy-Paste error, met often when the deadline is short :)

in .m file:

```
@implementation DetailGetter
... stuff here..
@end
```

than I have copy-paste an interface declaration above this, but with other name,

```
@implementation FromOtherMFile()
@end

@implementation DetailGetter
... stuff here..
@end
```

of course, if it is changed the FromOtherMFile to DetailGetter it will be no compiler error, but needed to scroll a whole page where is the error, and isn't highlighted in editor.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error message after upgrading from 4.2 to 4.3. By examining the dump, I was able to find the class name and the line that was causing the compiler to puke.

I'm sure the cause is different for everyone but adding my fix here.

Changing from

`[super.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];`

To

`[[super tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:0];`

addressed the problem for me. I thought dot notations translate to brackets though. It'd be great if someone could explain this fix which wasn't required in XCode 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In this code:

```
[super pxSeek:@"1"];
[super.SQL setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"SELECT COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT FROM ", super.Name]];
[super executeSQL];

return [super getIntColumn:0];
```

I need to change [super.SQL] for [[super SQL], that is invoking the method.

Answer (score 1):

im using xcode 4.3, have error like yours. It was some bug, i just reboot my computer and error gone.