# Xcode repeated build error code

Tags: xcode4

Am running Xcode 4.3 and have had this repeated error code for five times:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Have quite Xcode, and even rebooted the computer and got the same message which is listed as a Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 error command.

Does anyone else have this error message and know what to do about it?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that some folks found a partial solution in here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335012/apple-llvm-compiler-3-1-error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

Please copy/paste the message that clang says before crashing.

For me it was a enum declaration that made clang crash, only on Xcode 4.3.