# How to resolve Apple Mach-O Linker Error?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Here is a log

```
CompileC /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iPadNewsbookViewController.o Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG_MODE=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -mthumb "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -iquote "/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-project-headers.hmap" -iquote../src -I/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src -include /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iPortals_Prefix-gellvzrskltxesfcgpqcdmiyeqru/iPortals_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iPadNewsbookViewController.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iPadNewsbookViewController.dia -c /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.m -o /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iPadNewsbookViewController.o

In file included from /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.m:9:
In file included from /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.h:10:
In file included from /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/WebViewerController.h:10:
In file included from /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/AppDelegate_iPhone.h:12:
/Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/ShareKit/Reachability/Reachability.h:69:58: warning: declaration of 'struct sockaddr_in' will not be visible outside of this function
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;
                                                         ^
0  clang             0x000000010cadf6a2 PrintStackTrace(void*) + 34
1  clang             0x000000010cadfb29 SignalHandler(int) + 553
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff83d827ea _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff6b7b6300 _sigtramp + 18446744073300818736
4  clang             0x000000010c428828 findRetainCycleOwner(clang::Expr*, (anonymous namespace)::RetainCycleOwner&) + 312
5  clang             0x000000010c428b02 clang::Sema::checkRetainCycles(clang::Expr*, clang::Expr*) + 50
6  clang             0x000000010c44d33a clang::Sema::checkPseudoObjectAssignment(clang::Scope*, clang::SourceLocation, clang::BinaryOperatorKind, clang::Expr*, clang::Expr*) + 1242
7  clang             0x000000010bc85e86 clang::Sema::ActOnBinOp(clang::Scope*, clang::SourceLocation, clang::tok::TokenKind, clang::Expr*, clang::Expr*) + 1606
8  clang             0x000000010bc8507a clang::Parser::ParseRHSOfBinaryExpression(clang::ActionResult<clang::Expr*, true>, clang::prec::Level) + 570
9  clang             0x000000010bc7e4cb clang::Parser::ParseAssignmentExpression() + 171
10 clang             0x000000010bc7e401 clang::Parser::ParseExpression() + 17
11 clang             0x000000010bcd3bde clang::Parser::ParseExprStatement(clang::ParsedAttributes&) + 46
12 clang             0x000000010bc7de9c clang::Parser::ParseStatementOrDeclaration(clang::ASTOwningVector<clang::Stmt*, 32u>&, bool) + 1564
13 clang             0x000000010bc7d1b9 clang::Parser::ParseCompoundStatementBody(bool) + 409
14 clang             0x000000010c3fb1f0 clang::Parser::ParseLexedObjCMethodDefs(clang::Parser::LexedMethod&) + 272
15 clang             0x000000010bd1f6fe clang::Parser::ParseObjCAtEndDeclaration(clang::SourceRange) + 158
16 clang             0x000000010bcfd0d2 clang::Parser::ParseObjCAtDirectives() + 386
17 clang             0x000000010bc3e887 clang::Parser::ParseExternalDeclaration(clang::Parser::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, clang::Parser::ParsingDeclSpec*) + 759
18 clang             0x000000010bc3e519 clang::Parser::ParseTopLevelDecl(clang::OpaquePtr<clang::DeclGroupRef>&) + 249
19 clang             0x000000010bc2128b clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool) + 299
20 clang             0x000000010bc1fd19 clang::CodeGenAction::ExecuteAction() + 857
21 clang             0x000000010bbf20af clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 879
22 clang             0x000000010bbf0d3b clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) + 2683
23 clang             0x000000010bbe353e cc1_main(char const**, char const**, char const*, void*) + 5086
24 clang             0x000000010bbbdcd8 main + 648
25 clang             0x000000010bbbda44 start + 52
26 clang             0x0000000000000079 start + 18446744069217724009
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple thumbv7-apple-ios4.0.0 -S -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name iPadNewsbookViewController.m -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -target-abi apcs-gnu -target-cpu cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi soft -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-linker-version 131.3 -g -coverage-file /var/folders/2s/0vbgmlf914d3x7m4xjqwdfh80000gp/T/iPadNewsbookViewController-qXtlG9.s -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.0 -dependency-file /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iPadNewsbookViewController.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -iquote /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-project-headers.hmap -iquote ../src -include-pch /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/iPortals_Prefix-gellvzrskltxesfcgpqcdmiyeqru/iPortals_Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG_MODE=1 -D IBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -D IBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -D IBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -I /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Hope Demo-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/2s/0vbgmlf914d3x7m4xjqwdfh80000gp/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -std=c99 -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility hidden -fblocks -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fobjc-arc -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fsjlj-exceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/RAGOpoR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPortals-hfedckfrrkbpaeeekwhpwwkrxkgz/Build/Intermediates/iPortals.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPortals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iPadNewsbookViewController.dia -o /var/folders/2s/0vbgmlf914d3x7m4xjqwdfh80000gp/T/iPadNewsbookViewController-qXtlG9.s -x objective-c /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.m 
1.  /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.m:77:60: current parser token ';'
2.  /Users/RAGOpoR/Desktop/trunk/src/Classes/iPadNewsbookViewController.m:57:20: in compound statement ('{}')
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/2s/0vbgmlf914d3x7m4xjqwdfh80000gp/T/iPadNewsbookViewController-Q4pbhm.mi
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/2s/0vbgmlf914d3x7m4xjqwdfh80000gp/T/iPadNewsbookViewController-Q4pbhm.sh
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Comment: It seems that some folks found a partial solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335012/apple-llvm-compiler-3-1-error

Answer (score 2):

If this happens consistently at roughly the same location in your code, then
you seem to have found an internal error in the compiler, i think best way to proceed is to first submit this as a bugreport to apple ( the URL is listed in the output you pasted ).

And then, if you would like to proceed, try to make changes to the code you are trying to compile, like comment out the first half, then retry, then comment out the second half, and retry.  This should point to the code causing the internal compiler error.

Sometimes reordering some code will solve the problem for you. So at least you can continue developing.

Comment: it happen when i integrated Facebook SDK. if i remove it, all done.